# How to stop Cell from being highlighted when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UITableView` I use this code to **un-highlight** a cell when a user selects it:

```
...didSelectRowAtIndexPath...    
[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```

and

```
...cellForRowAtIndexPath...
[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```

However, if you then scroll the table so that the tapped cell is out of view, and then scroll it back into view, it becomes highlighted.

How can I stop the **highlight** from coming back after scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deselect it for good when you begin scrolling, you can do so in `UIScrollView`'s delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deselect it via the table view...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to select the UITableView, and in the Attribute Inspector, uncheck the box that says "Show Selection on Touch." This will prevent any highlight on all cells.